# How to check Object type variable is null or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to check object type variable is null or not. However it always true when object is null also.

Here is code:

```
    object o;

    List<string> strings = new  List<string>();

    o = strings;

    if(o != null)  \\ Always it returns true
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Please help me out from the above problem. Thanks in advance!

Edited: 
I am unable to check with **o.count()** also.It is not showing count method only object type variables showing.

Comment: Well, you assign `strings` instance to `o` object. It can't be null. `o` will be null if you write like: `o = null`.

Comment: Am empty list doesn't mean null. So if you assign `strings` to `o`, then it is not null, which is why the condition always return true

Comment: @AnuViswan, how should I check that condition?

Comment: `strings.Any()` should help you to check if the collection is empty or not.If you need to check it from `o`, you need to do `(o as List<string>).Any()`.

Comment: @AnuViswan, Actually, for example i created List<string> but I am using List<Person> p = new List<Person> and assign to object o .Here Person is class.In this case how should i check if p is empty list assigning to object o.I am assigning different list type to object. Then how should I check the condition?

Answer (score 1):

`o` is not `null` because you are assigning `strings` to `o` which has value. Its value is empty `List`. 
Your check will work if you won't assign value to `o` or assign `null`.

The reason why you cannot check `count` of `o` is that `o` is an object. `Object` itself is not a `List`. You should either check `count` of `string` with following:
`strings.Count()` or `strings.Any()` to check if there are any items in array or cast `object` to `List`.